# Adding 1 to range while doing loop

Tags: python

So im trying to make a small game, but when i try to add one more to the loop, it dosent continue the loop. Is there any other way I could do this?

```py
import random

chosenCard = 2

correctCard = 2


remove = random.randint(1, 3)
print(remove)

loop = 1

for i in range(loop):
    if remove == correctCard or remove == chosenCard:
        loop += 1
        print("remove == correctCard or remove == chosenCard --- Adding loop +1", loop)



print("Chosen", chosenCard)
print("Correct", correctCard)
print("remove", remove)
```

Comment: And I have tested this while variable remove is 2.

Comment: What about `while` instead of a `loop`?

Comment: Once the `range` is evaluated it returns a range object from `0` to `loop` ***at the moment of evaluation***. Changing the value of `loop` afterwards doesn't affect the `range` object... You might be better using a `while` loop instead...

Comment: @vojtam Wow, didn't even have a thought of using while. thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `while` loop.

```py
while loop > 0:
    if remove == correctCard or remove == chosenCard:
        loop += 1
        print("remove == correctCard or remove == chosenCard --- Adding loop +1", loop)
    loop -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because, changing a variable does not change an object created with it. Say you are in the shop and your wife wrote you a shopping list with `2 apples`. If your wife then remembers that her mother comes for a visit, she can think that she needs 3 apples, but that does not change the number on your shopping list. The same is the case in your code. At the time the `range` is created, `loop` has a value of 1. So the range is created with 1 value. Later changing `loop` does not automatically change the range object. A while loop would be appropriate here:

```py
import random

chosenCard = 2
correctCard = 2
remove = random.randint(1, 3)
loop = 1

while loop > 0
    if remove == correctCard or remove == chosenCard:
        loop += 1
        print("remove == correctCard or remove == chosenCard - Adding loop +1", loop)
    loop -= 1

print("Chosen :", chosenCard)
print("Correct :", correctCard)
print("Remove :", remove)
```